# Hibernate Managing Concurrent Transactions with Spring data

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, locking

I have an api to update some records in database. I may have multiple machines running same application, so I cannot lock it with program but with database. I want to "lock" the record when I read it, and release it after I update the value to database. If two requests reach the server together (or in a very short period), I hope one calculation could wait for the end of transaction of another one and base on the value of another one.

For example,

```
| <-- database has a record whose value is 1
|
| <-- request 1 arrives and get the record with value 1 and lock the record
| <-- request 2 arrives and find the record is locked therefore wait until it is ready
|
| <-- request 1 calculate value += 1
|
| <-- request 1 update the record and unlock the record
|
| <-- record has value of 2 now
|
| <-- request 2 can get the record now, whose value is 2 and lock the record
|
| <-- request 2 calculate value += 1
|
| <-- request 2 update the record and unlock the record
|
| <-- record has value of 3 now
|
v
```

The database I used is Oracle. I am using Spring Data JPA for running queries. And what I have tried is :

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/lock")
public @ResponseBody
String pessimisticLock() throws InterruptedException {
    testService.readAddOneThenSave();
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Service:

```
@Transactional // to release lock after the method ends
public void readAddOneThenSave() throws InterruptedException {

    // get the record and lock it with PESSIMISTIC_WRITE
    TestLock testLock = testLockRepository.findById(1L);
    // but both machine show the original value :(
    logger.info("testLock: {}", testLock);

    // to simulate two requests arrive same time
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    Long value = testLock.getValue();
    logger.info("value: {}", value);

    testLock.setValue(value + 1);
    testLockRepository.save(testLock);
}
```

Repository:

```
// lock when called and release until end of transaction
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) 
TestLock findById(Long id);
```

I tried running the application on two machine and make request at the "same" time. The second request start finding record after first request ends but I still got same record (value = 1) from two machine, even on the machine with latter request. Then I will have the result of value 2 from the above example, which is not I want.

Is my understanding to PESSIMISTIC_WRITE correct ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!